# Embed 3D models on website

Tags: html, 3d, sketchup

Is there a way to embed Sketchup models on a website? Preferably a free one, if it's a commercial solution I'd like a confirmation that it's actually worth the money... I know about the 3D warehouse thingy where you can rotate it (javascript and some images), but I can't upload anything to the 3D warehouse 'cause it always "resets the connection".

Comment: I figured out that the 3D model has to be smaller than 10MB and has to be in KMZ format to be able to upload it to the 3D Warehouse... Problem is that when I export a 3MB SKP file to KMZ it becomes 17MB... Something to be able to have it under 10MB in KMZ format would also be welcome.

Comment: Is there anyone with good knowledge of sketchup who can simplify this model so that in KMZ format it's under 10MB? I didn't make this myself, I was just asked to put it on a website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try the upcoming WebGL Functions in modern Browsers. There are some Javascript Libraries that can read model files and show them within your (HTML 5?) website. I have not used them yet, but try these links if this sounds interesting:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

https://github.com/timjb/sketchup-threejs/

Comment: Sketchup just seems to freeze on a white dialog with 2 radiobuttons when I try to *export to three.js*... I'll just keep it running in background, maybe it will suddenly be done exporting in an hour or so :p

Comment: I've seen some small (4K) files translated and they looked good. Don't know how your 3MBish file works out, wish you luck.

Comment: Doesn't really seem to be working for large models >.< Anyway, `three.js` seems to be a pretty good solution for smaller models, so your answer came closest.

Answer (score 6):

I made a patch of an example game in three.js. Added ColladaLoader and Sketchup model + Third Person Shooter controls: 
https://github.com/irony/Nemesis
Try it out (Works best in Chrome)

http://peaceful-woodland-4410.herokuapp.com/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use http://sketchfab.com, they even have a SketchUp exporter.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll have a look at it. Just found out about SketchFab today but had long since given up hope of ever getting this to work, so I didn't think about using it for this purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it without cost. See here: https://help.sketchup.com/en/article/3000258

EDIT:

There were some free rendering sites apart from Google, but they don't seem to be in operation anymore. Posting to the Google 3D warehouse is going to be your best bet. Regarding your problem posting there, try it with Chrome.

EDIT #2:
If you don't want to upload to Google 3D Warehouse, you can achieve a similar effect with a little work. 3D Warehouse doesn't actually give the visitor the power to manipulate something in 3D, but rather it lets them "rotate" the image horizontally by simply showing a series of preset images of the 3D from various angles. You can take shots of your 3D object, import to Photoshop and create your own gif of the spinning object. A little more work than relying on Google, so you'll have to decide if it's worth it.

EDIT #3: If all else fails you can simply post the 3D model on your site as a downloadable file and advise visitors to get Sketchup to view it.

Comment: `<iframe src='http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/mini?mid=5368e94d006f71f1ae682533f3f1d4dd&etyp=im&width=600&height=700' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' width='600' height='700'></iframe>` Where should I put the URL of the skp/kmz file?

Comment: `Regarding your problem posting there, try it with Chrome.` I tried it with Chrome and Firefox, both to no succes.

Comment: @Robin: If you want the visitor to be able to rotate to all angles, then the 3D warehouse is not the solution. See my 3rd edit.

Comment: ... 3D warehouse lets you do that. Well not up and down but left and right is close enough. And no providing it as a download is not an option...

Comment: You're wanting something viewable from a linux-based browser?